# ColletionView inside table view not displaying data correctly

Tags: uicollectionview, tableview

[Edit] If additional information is needed, I will be happy to provide it.

I have a situation that I have thus far been unable to figure out.  A Collection View embedded inside of a table view; I am using a data dictionary for the data, a total of 7 sections.  The problem is that on reloading the data it isn't reading the data dictionary correctly and it's displaying images and section names that do not go together.

One note: If I limit the dictionary to say 4 sections it works just fine, it is only when it's more than that that I am having the problem.

here is a copy of the data dictionary:

```
var data1 = [quoteData(sectionType: "For You", quotes: ["Categories/General.png"
            ]),
             
             quoteData(sectionType: "Free Today", quotes: ["Categories/Loneliness.png", "Categories/Setting Goals.png"
            ]),
             
             quoteData(sectionType: "Hard Times", quotes: ["Categories/Death.png", "Categories/Loneliness.png"
            ]),
             
             quoteData(sectionType: "Calm Down", quotes:["Categories/Appreciation.png", "Categories/Managing Anxiety.png"
            ]),
             
             quoteData(sectionType: "Relationships", quotes:["Categories/Friendship.png"
            ]),
             
             quoteData(sectionType: "Personal Growth", quotes: ["Categories/Confidence.png", "Categories/Courage.png"
            ]),
             
             quoteData(sectionType: "Spiritual and Philosophy", quotes: ["Categories/Poetry.png"
            ]),
]
```

View Controller is as follows:

```
extension CategoriesViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    
    //MARK: - Methods
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 200
    }
    
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return data1.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        return data1[section].sectionType
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell1", for: indexPath) as! CategoriesTableViewCell
        cell.collectionView.tag = indexPath.section

        guard let catCell = cell as? CategoriesTableViewCell else {
            return cell
        }
        
        catCell.didSelectItemAction = { [weak self]  String in
            self!.existingCat = (self?.defaults.string(forKey: "DefaultQuotes"))!
            self?.defaultCat = String
            if self?.defaultCat != "" {
                if self?.defaultCat != "General" {
                    self?.adAlert()
                } else {
                    // update
                    self?.defaults.set(self?.defaultCat, forKey: "DefaultQuotes")
                    self?.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
                }
            } else {
                self?.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
            }
        }
        return cell
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplayHeaderView view: UIView, forSection section: Int) {
        view.layer.borderWidth = 4
        view.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
        if section == 0 {
            view.tintColor = .clear
        } else {
            // view.tintColor = .colorFromHex("a5d7fa")
            view.tintColor = .colorFromHex("ffffff")
        }
        let header = view as! UITableViewHeaderFooterView
        header.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.black
        header.textLabel?.font = UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .title3)

    }
    
    func adAlert() {
        let showAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Unlock Quotes", message: nil, preferredStyle: .alert)
        //let image = UIImage(named: "MIsc/PaintBrushColor")
        
        showAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Watch Video", style: .default, handler: { action in
            // Show Ad & update
            self.showAd()
            if self.defaultCat == self.existingCat {
                self.defaults.set(false, forKey: "resetIndex")
            } else {
                self.defaults.set(true, forKey: "resetIndex")
            }
            // update the Default quotes data area and Highlight box
            self.defaults.set(String(self.defaultCat), forKey: "DefaultQuotes")
            // pop view controller
            self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
        }))
        showAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .default, handler: { action in
        }))
        self.present(showAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

The TableViewCell code:
class CategoriesTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

```
// Outlets
@IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

//Constants
let defaults = UserDefaults.standard

// Variables
var resetIndex: Bool = false
var myCat: String = ""
var didSelectItemAction: ((String) -> Void)?


//Methods
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
    collectionView.delegate = self
    collectionView.dataSource = self
    myCat = defaults.string(forKey: "DefaultQuotes")!
    resetIndex = defaults.bool(forKey: "ResetIndex")
}

override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}
```

}

extension CategoriesTableViewCell: UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell1", for: indexPath)
    let lblQuote = cell.viewWithTag(80) as? UILabel
    let dougie = data1[collectionView.tag].quotes[indexPath.row]
    // Get range 4 places from the start, and 6 from the end.
    let r = dougie.index(dougie.startIndex, offsetBy: 11)..<dougie.index(dougie.endIndex, offsetBy: -4)
    // Access the string by the range.
    let subString = dougie[r]
    myCat = String(subString)
    didSelectItemAction?(myCat)
    //collectionView.reloadData()
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return data1[collectionView.tag].quotes.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell1", for: indexPath) as! CategoriesCollectionViewCell
    let Defaults = UserDefaults.standard
    let defQuote = Defaults.string(forKey: "DefaultQuotes")
    cell.images.image = UIImage(named: data1[collectionView.tag].quotes[indexPath.row])
    let myLbl = cell.viewWithTag(80) as? UILabel
    let myIcon = cell.viewWithTag(83) as? UIImageView
    myIcon?.image = UIImage(named: "bed.double.circle")
    let padlock = cell.viewWithTag(81) as? UIImageView
    let dougie = data1[collectionView.tag].quotes[indexPath.row]
    // Get range 4 places from the start, and 6 from the end.
    let r = dougie.index(dougie.startIndex, offsetBy: 11)..<dougie.index(dougie.endIndex, offsetBy: -4)
    // Access the string by the range.
    let substring = dougie[r]
    myLbl?.text? = String(substring)
    if myLbl?.text == defQuote {
        // we are going to set the border
        cell.images?.layer.borderWidth = 2.5
        cell.images?.layer.borderColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
        cell.images?.clipsToBounds = true
    } else {
        cell.images?.layer.borderWidth = 0.0
        cell.images?.layer.borderColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        cell.images?.clipsToBounds = false
    }
    print(data1[collectionView.tag].sectionType)
    let doggie = getImg(Inb: String(substring))
    if doggie == "" {
        let strIcon = "CatIcons/" + String(substring) + ".png"
        myIcon?.image = UIImage(named: strIcon)
    } else {
        myIcon?.image = UIImage(systemName: doggie)
    }
    if myLbl?.text == "General" || data1[collectionView.tag].sectionType == "Free Today" {
        padlock?.isHidden = true
    } else {
        padlock?.isHidden = false
    }
    return cell
}

func getImg(Inb: String) -> String {
    var retVal: String
    switch Inb {
    case "General":
        retVal = "rainbow"
    case "Hope":
        retVal = "sunrise"
    case "Sleep":
        retVal = "bed.double.circle"
    case "Mindfulness":
        retVal = "brain.head.profile"
    case "Enjoy the Moment":
        retVal = "figure.2"
    case "Calm":
        retVal = "figure.yoga"
    default:
        retVal = ""
    }
    return retVal
}
```

}